# Spring boot application properties with different keys

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can i define a Object to read my application.mysql-databases by key:

```
swaw:
  stage: dev
  ip: x.x.x.x
  port: 3306
  databases:
    mysql:
      url: "jdbc:mysql://...."
      password:
        dba: AAA
        read: BBB
    mssql:
      url: "jdbc:mssql://...."
      password:
        dba: CCC
        read: DDD
    informix:
       ....
```

I try with this object:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swaw.databases")
public class Databases {

    private Map<String, DatabasesConfig> map;

    public static class DatabasesConfig {

        private String url;
        private Password password;
        //GETTER AND SETTER
```

i get per request: `{"ip":"1x.x.x.x","port":"3306","databases":null}`

Answer (score 0):

**@emoleumassi** - Try this one :

```
 @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "databases")
    public class Databases {     

            private String url;
            private Password password;
            //GETTER AND SETTER
    }
```